# Is there a charts package for LaTeX?

Tags: packages, charts

I wanted to include some more or less complex charts into my LaTeX document. I have attached a picture that shows an example how it should like. Is there any charts package in LaTeX that allows me to include such charts in my document? Or do I have to do that with Excel or any other tool?

[image]
Picture from the paper: The secret life of bugs: Going past the errors and omissions in software repositories

Comment: Could you edit your question title to something more specific, to make it easier for others to find this?

Comment: I think that the gradient decreases readability a lot. If your really like it, you should at least make it the other way around so that the right edges are sharp.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is my solution, always based on TikZ.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,shadings}
\newcommand{\barwidth}{2}
\newcommand{\barheight}{0.5}
\newcommand{\thescale}{100}

\newcommand{\setscale}[1]{\renewcommand{\thescale}{#1}}

\newcommand{\shadebar}[2][]{
\node[rectangle,minimum width=\barwidth cm,minimum height=\barheight cm,](a){};
\node[left] at(a.east){\ensuremath{#2\%}};
\ifnum#2=0
\def\shadebarwidth{0.01/\barwidth}
\else
\def\shadebarwidth{(#2/\thescale)*\barwidth}
\fi
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\node[left color=#1,right color=white,draw=white,minimum width=\shadebarwidth cm,minimum height=\barheight cm,right]at (a.west){};
\end{pgfonlayer}
}

\begin{document}
\setscale{20}
\noindent
\tikz{\shadebar[green]{16}}\\
\tikz{\shadebar[red]{10}}\\
\setscale{100}
\tikz{\shadebar[blue]{60}}\\
\tikz{\shadebar[green]{100}}

\vspace{5cm}
\begin{tabular}{lp{\barwidth cm}p{\barwidth cm}p{\barwidth cm}}
Probing for ownership &\setscale{20}\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{\shadebar[blue]{16}} &\setscale{70}\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{\shadebar[blue]{69}} & \setscale{55}\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{\shadebar[green]{52}}\\
Summit &\setscale{20}\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{\shadebar[blue]{1}} &\setscale{70}\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{\shadebar[blue]{2}} & \setscale{55}\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{\shadebar[green]{50}}\\
Probing for expertise &\setscale{20}\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{\shadebar[blue]{17}} &\setscale{70}\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{\shadebar[blue]{34}} & \setscale{55}\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{\shadebar[green]{49}}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Basically, it allows you to define bars in which you can customize the width, the color and the scale. This because, you may wonder to change scale factor for your charts.

> **INTRODUCING LABELS**

To introduce labels instead of simply numbers here is a solution:

```
\newcommand{\labeledshadebar}[3][]{
\node[rectangle,minimum width=\barwidth cm,minimum height=\barheight cm,](a){};
\node[left] at(a.east){#3};
\ifnum#2=0
\def\shadebarwidth{0.01/\barwidth}
\else
\def\shadebarwidth{(#2/\thescale)*\barwidth}
\fi
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\node[left color=#1,right color=white,draw=white,minimum width=\shadebarwidth cm,minimum height=\barheight cm,right]at (a.west){};
\end{pgfonlayer}
}
```

The new command should be used as:

```
\tikz{\labeledshadebar[green]{16}{yes}}For example, changing the `document` content into:

\begin{document}
\setscale{20}
\noindent
\tikz{\shadebar[green]{16}}\\
\tikz{\labeledshadebar[green]{16}{yes}}\\
\tikz{\shadebar[red]{10}}\\
\setscale{100}
\tikz{\shadebar[blue]{60}}\\
\tikz{\labeledshadebar[blue]{60}{no}}\\
\tikz{\shadebar[green]{100}}

\vspace{2cm}
\begin{tabular}{lp{\barwidth cm}p{\barwidth cm}p{\barwidth cm}}
Probing for ownership &\setscale{20}\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{\shadebar[blue]{16}} &\setscale{70}\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{\shadebar[blue]{69}} & \setscale{55}\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{\shadebar[green]{52}}\\
Summit &\setscale{20}\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{\shadebar[blue]{1}} &\setscale{70}\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{\shadebar[blue]{2}} & \setscale{55}\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{\shadebar[green]{50}}\\
Probing for expertise &\setscale{20}\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{\shadebar[blue]{17}} &\setscale{70}\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{\shadebar[blue]{34}} & \setscale{55}\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{\shadebar[green]{49}}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

it is possible to get:

[image]

> **Xparse implementation**

To make things easier and to have just one command, it is possible to redefine the above commands by means of an `xparse` definition:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\shadebar}{O{blue} m o}{%
\node[rectangle,minimum width=\barwidth cm,minimum height=\barheight cm,](a){};
\IfNoValueTF{#3}{%true
\node[left] at(a.east){\ensuremath{#2\%}};
}
{%false
\node[left] at(a.east){#3};
}
\ifnum#2=0
\def\shadebarwidth{0.01/\barwidth}
\else
\def\shadebarwidth{(#2/\thescale)*\barwidth}
\fi
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\node[left color=#1,right color=white,draw=white,minimum width=\shadebarwidth cm,minimum height=\barheight cm,right]at (a.west){};
\end{pgfonlayer}
}
```

Now the last example with labels could be simplified; in order to allow the customization inside the document of the `\barwidth` and the `\barheight`, I inserted two dedicated commands `\setbarwidth` and `\setbarheight`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,shadings}
\newcommand{\barwidth}{2}
\newcommand{\barheight}{0.5}
\newcommand{\thescale}{100}

% To allow customization inside the document
\newcommand{\setscale}[1]{\renewcommand{\thescale}{#1}}
\newcommand{\setbarwidth}[1]{\renewcommand{\barwidth}{#1}}
\newcommand{\setbarheight}[1]{\renewcommand{\barheight}{#1}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\shadebar}{O{blue} m o}{%
\node[rectangle,minimum width=\barwidth cm,minimum height=\barheight cm,](a){};
\IfNoValueTF{#3}{%true
\node[left] at(a.east){\ensuremath{#2\%}};
}
{%false
\node[left] at(a.east){#3};
}
\ifnum#2=0
\def\shadebarwidth{0.01/\barwidth}
\else
\def\shadebarwidth{(#2/\thescale)*\barwidth}
\fi
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\node[left color=#1,right color=white,draw=white,minimum width=\shadebarwidth cm,minimum height=\barheight cm,right]at (a.west){};
\end{pgfonlayer}
}

\begin{document}
\setbarwidth{3}
\setbarheight{0.75}
\setscale{20}
\noindent
\tikz{\shadebar[green]{16}}\\
\tikz{\shadebar[orange]{16}[yes]}\\
\tikz{\shadebar[red]{10}}\\
\setbarwidth{3.5}
\setbarheight{1}
\setscale{100}
\tikz{\shadebar{60}[no]}\\
\tikz{\shadebar[violet]{60}{no}}\\
\tikz{\shadebar[green!80!black]{100}}

\vspace{2cm}

\setbarwidth{2}
\setbarheight{0.5}
\begin{tabular}{lp{\barwidth cm}p{\barwidth cm}p{\barwidth cm}}
Probing for ownership &\setscale{20}\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{\shadebar{16}} &\setscale{70}\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{\shadebar{69}} & \setscale{55}\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{\shadebar[green]{52}}\\
Summit &\setscale{20}\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{\shadebar{1}} &\setscale{70}\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{\shadebar{2}} & \setscale{55}\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{\shadebar[green]{50}}\\
Probing for expertise &\setscale{20}\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{\shadebar{17}} &\setscale{70}\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{\shadebar{34}} & \setscale{55}\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{\shadebar[green]{49}}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this looks great. But what can I do if I want in the bar not the numbers, but e.g. text?
So as an example in Probing for ownership I want afterwards a bar with 16% but the text should be "yes"

Comment: Awesome answer! Used it that way!

Answer (score 13):

Such thing can easily be made with TikZ:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
mystyle/.style={inner sep=0pt, inner ysep = .5mm, anchor=west, text height=2mm},
mynum/.style={inner sep=0pt, inner ysep = .5mm, anchor=east}
}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\myrow}[4]{%
#1 & \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-2pt]\node at (0,0)[ fill = red, text width=#2 cm,mystyle] {}; \node[mynum] at (1cm,0){\pgfmathparse{int(round(#2*100))}\pgfmathresult}; \end{tikzpicture}&  %
 \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-2pt]\node at (0,0)[ fill = blue, text width=#3 cm,mystyle] {}; \node[mynum] at (1cm,0){\pgfmathparse{int(round(#3*100))}\pgfmathresult}; \end{tikzpicture}&%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-2pt]\node at (0,0)[ fill = green, text width=#4 cm,mystyle] {}; \node[mynum] at (1cm,0){\pgfmathparse{int(round(#4*100))}\pgfmathresult}; \end{tikzpicture}\\
}

\begin{tabular}{lp{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}}
\myrow{yes}{1}{.5}{.75}
\myrow{no}{.33}{.2}{.9}
\myrow{maybe}{.02}{.2}{.9}
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

There is on thing I have to say about your picture: I as a reviewer would reject that thing. Why? Well look at the scale. It's a rubber scale.  That means your projection point changes from cell to cell. Such cells can't be compared and the reader will get a false impression; e.g. 66 % and 52% look exactly the same. 
Now take a look at the result of mine: 100 % is always 1cm. This means (except small values) the projection is always the same.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the remark. It isn't actually my picture, I just used it as an example.

Answer (score 6):

See [spark](http://jblevins.org/projects/spark/), [sparklines](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/sparklines/) and [sparkln](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/tufte-latex/6vZXVVC5c-c/Q1rgUNOIwaMJ).

EDIT: Just noticed you also asked for Excel solutions.  For that see [sparklinesforxl on sourceforce](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sparklinesforxl/) (also see [sparlinesforxl main site](http://sparklines-excel.blogspot.ca/)) or use the sparkline functionality [built into Excel 2010](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16759/how-to-use-sparklines-in-excel-2010/) .

EDIT 2: Here is an example of using sparklinesforxl in Excel.  We used the `hbar` function here.  For example, if cell `a1` holds a fraction that we wish to display in light blue then we put the formula `=hbar(a1, 15128749)` into the cell where we want the bar to appear or to display it in light green use `=hbar(a1, 9498256)` .

There is a color chart [here](http://garr.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/sparklinesforxl/color_codes.pdf) which can be used to avoid color computations although in this example what I actually did was to start with RGB values of (144, 238, 144) for light green and (173, 216, 230) for light blue and use the formula `R + 256 * G + 256^2 * B` to get the corresponding numeric values shown in the last paragraph for argument 2.

[image: screenshot]

EDIT 3: And here is a `sparklines` package example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{sparklines}
\begin{document}

\setlength{\sparklinethickness}{5pt}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lllllll}

& \multicolumn{2}{l}{\bfseries E} & 
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\bfseries O} & 
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\bfseries E/O} \\

\bfseries First Line & 
    16\% & \definecolor{sparklinecolor}{RGB}{173,216,230}
    \begin{sparkline}{5} \spark 0.0 0.5 0.16 0.5 / \end{sparkline} &
    30\% & \definecolor{sparklinecolor}{RGB}{173,216,230}
    \begin{sparkline}{5} \spark 0.0 0.5 0.30 0.5 / \end{sparkline} &
    53\% & \definecolor{sparklinecolor}{RGB}{144,238,144}
    \begin{sparkline}{5} \spark 0.0 0.5 0.53 0.5 / \end{sparkline} \\

\bfseries Second Line & 
    10\% & \definecolor{sparklinecolor}{RGB}{173,216,230}
    \begin{sparkline}{5} \spark 0.0 0.5 0.10 0.5 / \end{sparkline} &
    20\% & \definecolor{sparklinecolor}{RGB}{173,216,230}
    \begin{sparkline}{5} \spark 0.0 0.5 0.20 0.5 / \end{sparkline} &
    50\% & \definecolor{sparklinecolor}{RGB}{144,238,144}
    \begin{sparkline}{5} \spark 0.0 0.5 0.50 0.5 / \end{sparkline} \\

\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Rather than just providing links, perhaps you could work up a small sample document that shows how to use the package?

Comment: These all contain examples in their documentation.

Comment: The idea of the Stackexchange model is that answers are supposed to be relatively self-contained.  Answers with just links are especially discouraged since they can often disappear.

Comment: OK. I have added a couple of examples.